# 3D models in Three js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, three.js, 3d

I am working on a personal website and it includes 3D models with Three js. When in desktop mode, everything is fine, you can scroll normally without any problem. However, in smaller devices, for example from a phone, the 3D model makes it difficult to scroll. When you move your finger on the screen, instead of scrolling, you rotate the 3D model. Is there any way that I can make the 3D model not interact in this way? For example let the 3D model auto rotate but not interact with it when the screen is clicked or touched.

I tried some setting some options in the  tag, for example, notInteract:true, which didn't do anything. enableRotate:false just makes the 3D model stay still, but the problem with scrolling didn't resolve. Tried to find some options for the  tag but couldn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.